# Pytest fails when data is too big

Tags: python, dictionary, pytest

My unit test are failing because of some parameters returns a big chunk of data. but when the failing parameters were isolated, it works fine.

Sample code snippet:

```
import pytest
import my_script

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
'params, results',
[
  (
   param_set_1,
   results_1
  ),
  (
  param_set_2,
  results_2
  ),
  ...
]

def test_my_func(params, result):
  assert my_script.my_function(params) == results
```

my_function returns a dict from some database and that dict could have at least 4 thousand keys. Running the pytest on all params causes failure for some params that returns a big chunk of dict(ie 4k keys). But when isolating the failed test and running them separately causes no issue.

How should I be able to run the unit test without partitioning the parameters?

Comment: By "fail" you mean you get an out of memory error or something like that? Or could it just be that the tests depend on each other in some way?

Comment: I don't believe I am having a memory error. The pytest run was able to print the fetched data but fails on the assert line. The returned data from the function is an empty dict even though it was able to fetch from the database.